# Javascript to generate random password with specific number of letters

Tags: javascript, security, random, passwords

I want to generate a password in a web page, on the client side, in Javascript. The password should use letters and numbers, perhaps some symbols. How can I generate a password in Javascript securely?

Comment: yes..but you need to show us what you have done..

Comment: sorry i didnt know that... ok i will

Comment: but ive only managed to make a script for generating a random password

Comment: never mind i figured it out :)

Comment: Since this is a request for a javascript why a tag of java?unnecessary

Answer (score 10):

Since a password needs to be unpredictable, it needs to be generated by a well seeded crypto PRNG. `Math.random` is usually not secure.

Modern browsers (At least the current versions of Firefox and Chrome) support `window.crypto.getRandomValues` which generates secure random values.

Presto based Opera doesn't support it, but its `Math.random` is secure. But since Opera has died, the fallback shouldn't be necessary anymore.

```
function randomString(length)
{
    var charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    var i;
    var result = "";
    var isOpera = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.opera) == '[object Opera]';
    if(window.crypto && window.crypto.getRandomValues)
    {
        values = new Uint32Array(length);
        window.crypto.getRandomValues(values);
        for(i=0; i<length; i++)
        {
            result += charset[values[i] % charset.length];
        }
        return result;
    }
    else if(isOpera)//Opera's Math.random is secure, see http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webcrypto/2013Jan/0063.html
    {
        for(i=0; i<length; i++)
        {
            result += charset[Math.floor(Math.random()*charset.length)];
        }
        return result;
    }
    else throw new Error("Your browser sucks and can't generate secure random numbers");
}

alert(randomString(10))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ebbpa/

Comment: I like this because I was looking for a solution that uses `crypto` and falls back on `Math.random()` but I was disappointed when I tested this. Using `randomString(7)` and `crypto` this function generates duplicates about 1 in 1000000. Not sure why, maybe the mod?

Comment: @jrode There are 3.5E12 strings with length 7, so per [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) collisions should become likely as you approach sqrt(3.5E12), which is about 2 million. This behaviour is expected even with a perfect RNG.

Comment: @jrode Note that my code only uses the `Math.random` fallback in presto based Opera, since it's not a good RNG is most browsers. For anything security relevant, you should first add a fallback for `msCrypto` to handle recent versions of IE and either fail or use a high quality RNG as fallback instead of `Math.random`.

Comment: This is great, and I upvoted this, but note since you use `charset[random_values[i] % charset.length]` to generate each random character (over the 62-character alphabet), you're basically generating 32 random bits for every (approximately) 5.95 bits you actually need. But this is actually good and I wouldn't recommend changing to Uint8Array, because as 62 is not a power of 2, `values[i] % charset.length` technically has a bias. This doesn't matter when you use Uint32Array, but can matter if you use Uint8Array: as 62*4 = 248, the values 248 to 255 mean that 0 to 8 are slightly more likely.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I considered rejection based sampling instead, but chose this approach for its simplicity, despite the slight bias and the performance impact. For my similar C# code I switched to 64 bit integers to further reduce the bias, but that's tricky to do in javascript.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

```
 var random=Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);//this gives you 7 alpha numeric characters.
 var timestamp =new Date().getTime();//this gives you epoch time
 var my_very_unique_password=(random+timestamp);//concat both..
 alert(my_very_unique_password);
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bP57B/

And if you dont want such huge passwords,just do `alert(random)`

Comment: Password (needs to be unpredictable) and `Math.random` is a bad combination, unless you're using opera.

Comment: well just replace that 7 with 10,15...and remove timestamp...why mathrandom is a bad option?

Comment: Because it's usually not a secure PRNG. Increasing the output size doesn't help when the underlying PRNG doesn't have a security level exceeding the output size.