# Is this is a good way to generate a secure random string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, random, cryptography

Below is some code I wrote to generate a random string in JavaScript. Are there any security issues if I use the values received from this method as salts or tokens for users?

```
String.random = function(length, characters) {
    length = length === undefined ? 32 : length;
    characters = characters === undefined ? 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789' : characters;

    var maxIndex = characters.length - 1;
    var string = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        string += characters[Number.random(0, maxIndex)];
    }

    return string;
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it may be a better fit at http://security.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: It makes me sad that there are so many Stack Exchanges.

Comment: @g.d.d.c While security.stackexchange.com looks more suitable for this question, I'm not sure they have the knowledge to answer this though. The basic point is: are there alternative ways to generate a random number in Javascript? Not so trivial.

Comment: if you dont want to do crypto your self i suggest to take a look at some bcrypt/blowfish libraries. Dont know any for js tho ;(

Comment: I recommend my answer to [Javascript to generate random password with specific number of letters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18121681/445517). It uses the secure PRNG built into browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [crypto.getRandomValues()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues) to get cryptographically secure random numbers in javascript, but they're not decimal numbers like Math.random(), so it takes more work to deal with them. Here's the plain javascipt solution with crypto.getRandomValues():

```js
function getCryptoRandomBetween(min, max){
  //the highest random value that crypto.getRandomValues could store in a Uint32Array
  var MAX_VAL = 4294967295;
  
  //find the number of randoms we'll need to generate in order to give every number between min and max a fair chance
  var numberOfRandomsNeeded = Math.ceil((max - min) / MAX_VAL);
  
  //grab those randoms
  var cryptoRandomNumbers = new Uint32Array(numberOfRandomsNeeded);
  crypto.getRandomValues(cryptoRandomNumbers);
  
  //add them together
  for(var i = 0, sum = 0; i < cryptoRandomNumbers.length; i++){
    sum += cryptoRandomNumbers[i];
  }
  
  //and divide their sum by the max possible value to get a decimal
  var randomDecimal = sum / (MAX_VAL * numberOfRandomsNeeded);
  
  //if result is 1, retry. otherwise, return decimal.
  return randomDecimal === 1 ? getCryptoRandomBetween(min, max) : Math.floor(randomDecimal * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function getRandomChar(str){
  return str.charAt(getCryptoRandomBetween(0, str.length - 1));
}

String.random = function(length, characters) {
  for(var i = 0, str = ""; i < length; i++) str += getRandomChar(characters);
  return str;
};

console.log(String.random(60, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"));
```

Pretty rough on the eyes, but it works. If you want a simpler solution, my preference is [rando.js](https://github.com/nastyox/Rando.js). it works for plain javascript as well as Node.js/React. You can use `rando(str)` to get a random character from a string, so building a random string the way you want is as simple as:

```js
String.random = function(length, characters) {
  for(var i = 0, str = ""; i < length; i++) str += rando(characters);
  return str;
};

console.log(String.random(60, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"));
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/2.0.0.js"></script>
```

Let me reiterate that the strings both of these solutions generate have enough entropy to be safe for use as passwords, salts, or tokens for users.

Answer (score 0):

I think it all reduces to finding an alternative way to generate random numbers in Javascript, not relying on `Math.random`.

Once you have an alternative to `Math.random`, you can generate your random string in an almost identical way. I suggest to have a look at the [Mersenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) algorithm. There are quite a few Javascript implementations around (some are even in the Wikipedia page I linked).

Like many random number generators, you have to start with a seed: you can generate one with `Math.random`, adding an additional "salt" if you like.

Comment: MT is not secure and since `Math.random` is not secure in most browsers it's not a good idea to use it to generate the seed.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Who talked about browsers? It may be NodeJS. Anyway, you should post an answer using `crypto`, I actually didn't know about it.

Comment: If you use `Math.random` as the seed for MT, your MT random number sequence will be only as secure as `Math.random`. There is no way to computationally generate security. (i.e. create entropy) Since it is *not* secure, do not use it for anything security related. use `window.crypto.getRandomValues()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using crypto library to generate random string in NodeJs

```
import { randomBytes } from 'crypto';

function random(length) {
    return randomBytes(Math.ceil(length / 2)).toString('hex').slice(0, length);
}

const randomString = random(10);
```

Comment: A random string generated in this way would only contain the characters used as hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

Using `crypto.getRandomValues` you can easily generate a secure random identifier:

```js
function genId(){
  let array = new Uint8Array(16);
  crypto.getRandomValues(array);
  return btoa(array);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure you were aware of this but `btoa(array) == btoa(array.toString())`. In other words, `btoa` coerces input to string in the conventional manner (invoking `toString` on the input). For an array it's the equivalent to `array.join(',')`.

Answer (score 0):

I really liked Satish answer, but wanted something with more range than just hex values so I made it a little longer. I also like the use of bota in the mildred code. Seems much simpler, but alas here is my take on the question.

```
let { randomBytes } = require('crypto')

let encodeChars="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^*()[]{};<>?";

function randomStr(length) {
    let rb = randomBytes(length);
    let r = "";
    for (i = 0; i < rb.length; i++) {
        let j = rb[i] % encodeChars.length;
        r = r+encodeChars[j];
    }

    return(r);
}

let token = randomStr(10);
console.log(token);
```