# Is it okay to utilize Math.random() to generate a Password-Reset-Key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, cryptography, authorization

I had a very basic idea for a simple algorithm that would allow a user to reset their password by requesting a random code sent to their e-mail.

If a user forgets their PW, they can request the server to generate a reset code and send it to them as email. This code is then appended to their user entry in the DB. A confirmation input form will ask the user to type the reset code on the frontend - if they fail, the code will be flagged and invalidated. If they succeed, they are sent to a new PW reset form, where they can update their credentials to be replaced through a `PUT` request to the backend.

Here is my basic idea -

```
function generate7KeyPasswordResetConfirmationCode() {

    const arrayOfSeven = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

    const alphabet = [Array of 26 Lowercase Chars and 26 Uppercase Chars]

    const letterOrNumber = arrayOfSeven.map(currentPos => {
        // return pseudorandom number between 0-100
        const oneToOneHundred = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(101))
            if (oneToOneHundred < 50) { return "char" }
            else if (oneToOneHundred >= 50) { return "num" }        
    })

    const resetKey = letterOrNumber.map(numOrChar => {
        // return pseudorandom number between 0-51 and return a-z-A-Z
        if (numOrChar === "char") {
            const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(52))                
              return alphabet[index]
        }
        // return pseudorandom number 0-9
        if(numOrChar === "num") { 
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(10)) 
        }
    })

        return resetKey
}
```

However, my method involves Math.random(), and I noticed this thing on MDN:

`Math.random() does not provide cryptographically secure random numbers. Do not use them for anything related to security. Use the Web Crypto API instead, and more precisely the window.crypto.getRandomValues() method`

I realize I could just use a uuid4, but I wanted to create my own solution - how exactly can this be cracked? If I invalidate the code with the first failed attempt, what else could go wrong?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Using random numbers to generate passwords is completely different to using them for cryptography.

Comment: The general idea is just to create a randomized string of length `7` - use math.rand() twice, so two things are randomized - whether a given index is a number or letter - and the actual number or letter. It's just meant to be a simple method to allow a user to change their PW - the actual PW encryption is done with bcrypt on the backend

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RandomSource/getRandomValues

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, I saw this one - however the docs are not really sufficient for me to understand it. What is the range of numbers returned? It seems to be between negative and positive 150? I need to be able to control but randomize the range of numbers. Anyway, I tried my solution and it forms a randomized 7 character key, with letters/number position randomized. With some further encryption layers I think this is a sufficient solution.

Comment: A random generated password should have similar security as a random generated key. So try https://stackoverflow.com/a/18121681/589259 - don't forget to vote up my friend Codes :) Note that the randomization of that code is quite but not fully random as there may be a tiny bias because of the floating point operations. Now *that* is probably not an issue; at least a lot less of an issue than using `Math.random()` which might for instance be influenced by other JavaScript used in the browser (!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, using a non-secure random number generator is *never* a good idea. A randomly generated password should have similar properties as a randomly generated key. There is no guarantee that the random number generator cannot be influenced by other scripts. In the worst case scenario other scripts could find out the state of the random number generator and directly calculate your password.

So please use [`window.crypto.getRandomValues(array)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RandomSource/getRandomValues) to generate a password. An - as good as - unbiased implementation to retrieve a password from the *secure* random number generator can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18121681/589259).

---

If you don't have access to the random number generator then:

1. obtain a secure random from the server;
2. add random entropy (mouse movements, the system time, some insecure random values etc.) from the client and concatenate them to the random from the server;
3. perform a secure calculation such as a hash or PRNG implementation over the resulting array to create random numbers;
4. use (3) to create the password.

---

You should definitely only do this over a secured connection, and keep in mind phishing attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer - How is it possible to handle browser that does not support crypto object? In your friend's code, he simply throws an error. I guess this is the best we can do - refuse to reset password of someone who is using older browser, since it may be an attacker exploiting the system?

Comment: I think I tried to cover that in the second part. In general you try to mix a strong random from the server with the weaker random from the client. That way the password is not just dependent on the server and the random can still not be guessed on the client by other scripts etc. I agree, that's not that simple, but security generally isn't. But note that all desktop browsers seem to support the object by now. Trickier is when the client disables JavaScript.